# How to handle exception that is thrown inside a general try catch?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have a method like this:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        //Some code

        if(myCondition == false)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation is not valid because...");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The problem with that is that when I throw the invalid operation exception, it is chatched by the general exception, so the consumer of the method doesn't know that it is an ivalid operation exception.

One option it would be rethrow the invalid operation exception:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        //Some code

        if(myCondition == false)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation is not valid because...");
        }
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

But in this case, the track trace tells that the exception happens in the next line of the throw. At least it is not tells that the line of exception is in the throw inside the catch.

But is there another better way to keep the original exception when I throw and exception inside a general try / catch?

Or perhaps are there better options?

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a functional difference between the two pieces of code you've shown. Why are you catching to simply rethrow anyway?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama if you mean why I catch to rethrow in the first case, I was doing it to catch any unexpected exception that perhaps it is not Exception neither InvalidOperationException.

Comment: you will never see an exception that is not an `Exception` (technically such a beast exists, but: the runtime fakes it for you by default - you need to explicitly disable it via `[RuntimeCompatibiliy(WrapNonExceptionThrows = false)]`, which: you aren't doing); and `catch`ing something *just* to `throw`: completely pointless - just remove the `try`/`catch` entirely, unless you're doing something more useful

Comment: But the point is you don't have to catch the exception at all if all you want to do is have it bubble up. An exception will naturally bubble up to the caller if not caught.

Comment: Oddly enough, if I try your code on .NET Framework (v4.8.1), I see that the line number referenced in the Stack Trace is indeed the `throw;` line, but if I try it against .NET 7, the line referenced is the `throw new InvalidOperationException` line. I guess Microsoft fixed it so it references the correct line of the method?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-exception-ctor(system-string-system-exception)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you `catch` `InvalidOperationException` exception within `MyMethod` at all? It's a *caller* not `MyMethod` which is *responsible* to act on `InvalidOperationException`. Note, that if `MyMethod` knows how to act if condition is not met, it should just act, without throwing any exception.

- `MyMethod` *throws* - "I can't perform the operation because ..." - and I *don't know what to do*.
- Caller *catches* - if `MyMethod` fails and the reason is "because ..." then, say "write to the log and do SomeOtherMethod".

Let's program by contract:

```
public void MyMethod() {
  // Contract: to perform we need some conditions be met:
  if (!myCondition) 
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation is not valid because...");

  // Add more conditions here

  // From now on we are satisfied with conditions
  DoMainOperation();
}
```

Usage (caller)

```
var myClass = new MyClass();

...

try {
  // Let's call MyMethod
  myClass.MyMethod();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException e) {
  // MyMethod Failed, here we react, e.g.

  // Log the error 
  myLogger.LogException(e);

  // Try some other method and if it's failed re-throw
  if (!myClass.OtherMethod())
    throw;
}
```